# Laravel 5.8 method not supported error using register route

Tags: laravel

Lavavel 5.8 version. I'm getting route method error while using "register" Route.

```
<form action="{{url('register')}}" method="get" class="at-formtheme at-formcategories">
@csrf
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/','EmployeeController@index'); 
Route::post('signup-detail','EmployeeController@signup_detail');
Route::post('store-employee','EmployeeController@store_employee');
Route::post('store-interest','EmployeeController@store_interest');
```

Comment: the error looks like you are trying to use a `GET` request to a `POST` route.

Comment: Change the method to: `POST`

Comment: Can you show your routes file?

Comment: Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/','EmployeeController@index');
Route::post('signup-detail','EmployeeController@signup_detail');
Route::post('store-employee','EmployeeController@store_employee');
Route::post('store-interest','EmployeeController@store_interest');

Comment: i tried "post" method but issue is not resolved

Comment: do `php artisan route:list` and show it to us

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses a POST request for the default auth scaffolding. Change your form HTML tag to this:

```html
<form action="{{url('register')}}" method="POST" class="at-formtheme at-formcategories">
```

Comment: when i use "get" method it redirect back with URL containing request data.

Comment: <form action="{{url('register')}}" method="post" class="at-formtheme at-formcategories">

Comment: It is redirecting back because of validation error,
If you put

`@if(count($errors))
@foreach($errors as $error)
<li>{{$error}}</li>
@endforeach
@endif`

You will see the validation errors

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use named roads rather than the url (for greater maintainability)

```
<form action="{{route('register')}}" method="POST" class="at-formtheme at-formcategories">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was using two post method for submit forms (one post request send data on second form then submit) and use return back() method in my controller so the exception was through again and again.